# Find the longest repeated pattern in a string

Tags: algorithms, strings, subsequences

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to find the longest repeated pattern in a string.

For example, consider the following string of numbers:

`5431428571428571428571428571427623874534`.

As you can see, `142857142857` is the longest pattern which is repeated for a couple of times (at least twice) in this string.

The repeated string should not contain any re
any idea rather than brute-force?

Comment: You did not define what “a couple of times” means, but if “twice” counts as “a couple of times,” then `142857` is not the longest because `142857142857` is longer.  I think that you should edit the question to clarify what you mean by “repeated pattern.”

Comment: very good point. I will update the question.

Comment: Are you requiring the occurrences of the pattern to be disjoint from each other? Because if not, 142857142857 is still not the longest repetition; 142857142857142857142 occurs twice. In any case, the usual answer to questions like this is "suffix trees".

Answer (score 16):

The problem is surprisingly non-trivial. First, two brute force algorithms. A square ("repeated pattern") is given by its *length* $\ell$ and position $p$, and takes time $O(\ell)$ to verify. If we go over all $\ell$ and $p$, we obtain an $O(n^3)$ algorithm. We can improve on that by first looping over $\ell$, and then scanning the string with two running pointers at a distance of $\ell$. In this way, one can verify whether a square of length $2\ell$ exists in linear time, giving a total running time of $O(n^2)$.

Kolpakov and Kucherov developed an algorithm for finding all *maximal repeats* in a word in time $O(n)$ [1], and their algorithm can be used to find all maximal squares in time $O(n)$. A *repeat* is a subword of the form $w^kx$, where $k \geq 2$ and $x$ is a proper prefix of $w$. The largest square contained in that repeat is $(w^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor})^2$. Using this formula, given all maximal repeats in a word (of which there are only $O(n)$ many), one can find the largest square.

---

[1] Kolpakov, R., & Kucherov, G. (1999). [Finding maximal repetitions in a word in linear time](http://monge.univ-mlv.fr/~koutcher/PAPERS/KolpakovKucherovFOCS99.pdf). In *Foundations of Computer Science, 1999. 40th Annual Symposium on* (pp. 596-604). IEEE.